# Is it possible to use Serenity with Cucumber-JVM for parallel test run?

Tags: cucumber-jvm, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

I am using Serenity with Cucumber-JVM. Can I configure my tests to run in parallel to reduce execution time?

Comment: You using gradle or maven ? You need to configure there.

Answer (score 0):

Cucumber-jvm is not [thread-safe](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/issues/630). That being said, you can look [here](https://github.com/temyers/cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin) and [here](https://opencredo.com/test-automation-concepts-parallel-test-execution/) for a solution that assigns a test runner to each feature file.